# Bash: Error in assigning default value to a variable

Tags: bash, variable, parameter, defaults, bash-expansion

Inside my bash script:

This works:

```
CWD="${1:-${PWD}}"
```

But, if I replace it with:

```
CWD="${1:=${PWD}}"
```

I get the following error

```
line #: $1: cannot assign in this way
```

Why I can't assign to ${1}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From bash's manpage:

```
Positional Parameters
    A  positional  parameter  is a parameter denoted by one or more digits,
    other than the single digit 0.  Positional parameters are assigned from
    the  shell's  arguments when it is invoked, and may be reassigned using
    the set builtin command.  Positional parameters may not be assigned  to
    with  assignment statements.  The positional parameters are temporarily
    replaced when a shell function is executed (see FUNCTIONS below).
```

and later, under **Parameter Expansion**

```
${parameter:=word}
       Assign  Default  Values.   If  parameter  is  unset or null, the
       expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of param‐
       eter  is  then  substituted.   Positional parameters and special
       parameters may not be assigned to in this way.
```

If you want to assign a default value to the positional parameter `$1` like in your question, you can use

```
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  CWD="$1"
else
  shift 1
  set -- default "$@"
  CWD=default
fi
```

Here I've used a combination of `shift` and `set`. I've just come up with this and I'm not sure if it's the proper way to change a single positional parameter.

Comment: Additionally, to assign something to `$1`, you would use e.g. `set -- "$PWD"` (this would clear the other positional parameters though, unless you did `set -- "$PWD" "$@"`, which would "push" `$PWD` to the front of `$@`).

Comment: @Kusalananda: I wonder if you can change a single pos. parameter. I've now tried a combination of `set` and `shift`, see my edit.

Comment: Oh, and I probably forgot the `--`, just in case some of the arguments start with a hyphen. Thanks @Kusalananda

Comment: Simplified: `if [ -z "$1" ]; then shift; set -- default "$@"; fi; CWD="$1"`